# Access to Imgur was denied

Tags: php, laravel, api, imgur

I want to access the image that I have uploaded but Imgur API showing access denies with `403 error`. On the other hand, if I copy the url of the image and paste in a new tab, it showed me the picture uploaded. How to figure it out, I'm stuck here.

Comment: If you are trying on local machine, try changing your local URL from http://127.0.0.1 to http://localhost. I was facing similar issue today and this worked for me.

Comment: @Animesh Thank you, It worked!

Answer (score 2):

I believe its an issue with the user agent or you might be using incorrect url. Please share your code snippet.

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was with the localhost and 127.0.0.1. And Thank you by the way.